# Change keyboard shortcut for Basic Code Completion in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

There is very important shortcut for "Basic Code Completion" in IntelliJ IDE which assumed to be invoked as <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut on Mac. The problem is this shortcut is *system* one and used to invoke "Spotlight" in Mac OS X Lion.

How you guys invoke it then?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You either disable/change Spotlight shortcut in the system settings or you change the Basic completion shortcut in IDEA `Preferences` | `Keymap`.

Answer (score 31):

I think that the question is mostly asking to what key combination do you change it, and why JetBrains haven’t implemented the update to the Mac keymap by themselves.

Anyways, I’ve swapped the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> with <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which doesn’t seem to collide with any Mac OS X system key shortcut.

Comment: Do you mean `option+space`?

Comment: @BenCarp if use windows OS , `option` key is  `windows button`

Answer (score 9):

You can override the OSX spotlight shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA/Services/Services Preferences. More info: [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph18418?locale=en_US).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I dont know if this helps but here is a list of the default key mappings http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf and you can change them from the menu `IDE Settings -> Keymap`

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use `Ctrl + Shift + Space` for "[SmartType](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html)" to avoid collision with Spotlight.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, spotlight is started by COMMAND-space and not by CTRL-space ...

Comment: I guess they changed meaning of this hotkey some time in the past. Anyway, Ctrl+Space is used by the system (switch keyboard layout) and cannot be used by IDE.

Comment: Cmd-space always opened spot light: http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/09/spotlight-keyboard-shortcuts/

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut for code compeletion for intelliJ IDEA in MacOS is

**Ctrl+Option+Space** ,

It Works for me, Try this, it may work

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control ^</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> collides with the *"Select the previous input source"* system shortcut, not Spotlight.

To fix this, go to System Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts... → Input Sources, and uncheck *"Select the previous input source"*, or change it's shortcut to something else:

[image: uncheck "Select the previous input source"]

Now restart IDEA, remove the keybinding and add the same keybinding back:

[image: IDEA keybinding]

Dunno why I needed these additional steps, but now it finally works.