# Shortcut key to list attribute value in xml layouts in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, when I open a layout file in text mode and enter in an attribute such as:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

It would be nice if there was a keyboard shortcut that I could use to list all the available attribute values for the attribute. In the above example, if I enter the letter "m", it presents me with matches including "match_parent". But I would like to see all the available attribute values.

Comment: Usually all attributes should be shown in the drop-down when the value string is empty (`""`), and the cursor is inside it. If it isn't visible, try pressing `Ctrl + Space`. That usually displays the possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately Ctrl + Space on a Mac brings up the Spotlight Search input which is part of the OS.

Comment: This might help then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085913/basic-code-completion-in-intellij-on-mac

Comment: @TheGamer007 You can move your solution into an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Basic Code Completion' shortcut can be used for this. The default keymap is `Ctrl + Space`. For Mac users, this will clash with the shortcut for Spotlight, and they can set a custom keymap or follow one of the other solutions given at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085913/basic-code-completion-in-intellij-on-mac).